# Constraint wit.ai keyword with regular expression

Tags: regex, wit.ai

Is there any way to constrain keywords in wit.ai to match certain patters using regular expressions or duckling?

I see that certain use cases have been built in (i.e. wit/location) but in my case the parser needs to pick up ids generated by my server.  The ids are generated with a constrained set of characters `[-a-zA-Z0-9_]` and wit can sometimes guess them but other times it will only parse part of the id.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and what I did was parsing those IDs before I send them to Wit and replace them with something like %ITEM_ID% and in Wit I created a entity item_id with keyword %ITEM_ID%. Also in my backend i save those IDs captured as part of the context. Makes sense?

Would be great to get a official answer regarding this.